# Why are temperature and specific volume independent properties in thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, entropy, volume

If we have a sealed piston-cylinder with gas inside and we heat it from the outside, the temperature changes. At the same time, if we look at it as a control mass system,the volume increases as the gas expands. Mass remains same. Hence specific volume changes too. So how can temperature and specific volume always be independent?

Comment: Would the default situation be that parameters are assumed—via [Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) or the principle of parsimony—independent unless they're found to be coupled?

Comment: What happens when you heat the gas in a strong metal cylinder whose volume does not expand? Thermodynamics isn't just for cylinders with moving pistons.

Answer (score 0):

Take gas in a box with a fixed size and heat it. The temperature increases, but the specific volume remains fixed. This is also a perfectly reasonable physical situation thatwe could easily achieve. Comparing this situation with the one in your question, we conclude that while I *can* increases the temperature and the specific volume together I don't *have* to. In other words we have more than one degree of freedom in the state of our system (in fact for a fixed mass of gas it turns out there are exactly two) and we can treat these two as independent.

Answer (score 0):

Temperature and (specific) volume are not the only possible choice of variables, although it is the one usually used in introductory thermodynamics courses. The choice is really a matter of convenience, but imposes the use of an appropriate [thermodynamic potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_potential) - one could use entropy in pressure as independent variables instead of temperature and volume respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ideal gas its behaviour is described by the ideal gas equation  $$PV=nRT$$ where $n$ and $R$ are constant for a given mass of gas.

The equation can be rearranged to describe any one of the three variables in terms of the other two, and which two you choose as the independent variables is entirely a matter of convenience.

Of course you have used specific volume (which amounts to $\frac{V}{n}$), and the equation will be more complex for a real gas. However you will still be able to use any two of the three variables (pressure, temperature, specific volume) as the independent variables.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are *independent* if we can construct systems in which we can pick each value independently. Dependent variables are those whose value is fixed by choices we made already.

The number of independent variables is given by the Gibbs rule, $F = N+2-\pi$, where $N$ is the number of components and $\pi$ is the number of phases. For a single phase ($\pi=1$) pure substance ($N=1$) the number of independent variables is $F=1+2-1=2$. *Which* two is up to us. We may pick $T$ and $V$, or $T$ and $P$, or many other combinations.

When we heat a closed box, we have effectively chosen $V$ (the volume of the piston) and $T$ (via heating). If we heat a cylinder fitted with a movable piston, we have effectively picked $T$ (via heating) and $P$ (via the mechanical equilibrium condition on the piston). In the first example $P$ is a dependent variable, as pressure increases inside a closed rigid box under heating. In the second example pressure is an independent variable, which we may control by the weight of the piston.

Regardless of which pair we pick as the independent variables, once this pair is fixed all other variables become dependent. And since we are free to choose the pair of independent variables, the same variable may be independent in one setting and depended in another.